# Creating links based on unique attributes from a Rails class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

My Rails model 'Product' has a string attribute called 'Brand'. I am trying to create a list of links consisting of the unique brands I have as attributes in my products. I am able to list the unique brands, but need help setting up the routes/controller structure. In the StoreController I have a method 'brand' that should trigger the filtered @products based on my :brand parameter. It looks like this:

My StoreController:

```
  def index
    @brands = Product.uniq.pluck(:brand)
  end 

  def brand
    @products = Product.find(params[:brand])
    render 'store/index'
  end
```

My view:

```
  <% @brands.each do |brand| %>
    <%= link_to brand, brand_store_path(brand) %>
  <% end %>
```

My routes.rb:

```
  resource :store do
   collection do
    get ':brand' => 'store#brand', :as => 'brand'
   end
  end
```

I assume the structure of this is not right, as I am currently trying to set up URL consisting of the name (Sting) for each of the different brands, e.g: localhost:3000/store/brand1, localhost:3000/store/brand2 etc...

thanks in advance for any structural advice/guiding on how to get this right!

Comment: What association is set between `products` and `stores`?

Comment: Store is just the layout,namespace and the view. Not even a model.

Comment: The result of clicking these links should be to filter @products to only contain the brand from the clicked link.

Comment: This issue was fixed using Scopes in Rails. I simply created a scope that used brandname as parameter:

Comment: So,you have fixed the issue now?

Comment: Yes I have, thanks Pavan.

Comment: Post it as answer and accept it.

Comment: Thank you Pavan, yes it was fixed!